# UI thread blocks on data update

Tags: angularjs, dom, reactjs

So, it's hard to build long, infinitely scrollable lists with lots of bindings without compromising performance. There are many ways to overcome that, but I noticed one particular problem I have no idea how to solve.

Basically if you have long `ng-repeat` with lots of items and whenever you append or change the data - UI blocks horrendously. The more data you update - longer the freeze.

[you can see it on that jsBin](http://jsbin.com/penuhilahujo/1/edit) - everytime you click the button UI freezes

Is there a way around that?

upd: I thought maybe I should try React and studied this [popular post](http://www.williambrownstreet.net/blog/2014/04/faster-angularjs-rendering-angularjs-and-reactjs/) about using React with Angular - seems React won't solve this problem, see this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/YnF7Vn?p=preview)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Infinite scrolling with React JS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21238667/infinite-scrolling-with-react-js)

Comment: +1. Certainly a duplicate. Might I add that React is very good at occlusion culling because of the DOM diffing and reuse of actual DOM elements. See the occlusion culling part at http://jlongster.com/Removing-User-Interface-Complexity,-or-Why-React-is-Awesome