# Create react components with onWheel Event

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to create components while scrolling. Is it a good idea to use lodash's range method and increase it?

It looks like this:

```
_.range(4);
// => [0, 1, 2, 3]
```

So i can do something like this:

```
_.range(someState)
```

and in onWheel event I would just increment someState.

I'm not sure if this is a good idea tho. What do you think?

Comment: do you mean you want an infinite scroll type thing?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a solution but you could have a look at [react-infinite-scroller](https://github.com/CassetteRocks/react-infinite-scroller). Basically, the lib is listening to a scroll event and renders elements with React.createElement.

Comment: Yes, I want infinite scroll type thing :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Infinite scrolling with React JS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21238667/infinite-scrolling-with-react-js)